# Split string into array then loop, in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I have Googled this a LOT but my C# skills are pretty terrible and I just can't see why this isn't working.

I have a string which comes from a session object, which I don't have any control over setting.  The string contains some sentences separated by six underscores.  e.g.:

```
Sentence number one______Sentence number two______Sentence number three etc
```

I want to split this string by the six underscores and return each item in the resultant array.

Here's the code I have:

```
string itemsPlanner = HttpContext.Current.Session["itemsPlanner"].ToString();

string[] arrItemsPlanner = itemsPlanner.Split(new string[] { "______" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (string i in arrItemsPlanner)
{
  newItemsPlanner += "debug1: " + i;  //This returns what looks like a number, as I'd expect, starting at zero and iterating by one each loop.
  int itemNumber;

  try
  {
    itemNumber = Convert.ToInt32(i);
    string sentence = arrItemsPlanner[itemNumber].ToString();
  }
  catch (FormatException e)
  {
    return "Input string is not a sequence of digits.";
  }
  catch (OverflowException e)
  {
    return "The number cannot fit in an Int32.";
  }
  finally 
  {
    return "Fail!"
  }
}
```

Whenever I run this, the session is being retreived successfully but the line which says: itemNumber = Convert.ToInt32(i); fails every time and I get an error saying "Input string is not a sequence of digits."

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample of your session string? Try trim Convert.ToInt32(i.Trim()).

Comment: Post sample value for `itemsPlanner` - is it something like `1______6______1`?

Comment: If your input string was `324534______1162______12432` instead of "sentences" then your question would make more sense. Also, why are you converting to an integer then back to a string? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What type is `newItemsPlanner`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your case `i` is not a number, it's the actual element in the array. A foreach loop has no iteration variable, you only have access to the actual element being iterated through `i`.

So first loop itareation i is *Sentence number one*, then *Sentence number two*.

If you want the number, you have to use a for loop instead.

So something like this

```
for( int i = 0; i < arrItemsPlanner.length; i++ ){
  //on first iteration here
  //i is 0
  //and arrItemsPlanner[i] id "Sentence number one"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get each sentence and do something with it, this will do the trick:

```
string itemsPlanner = HttpContext.Current.Session["itemsPlanner"].ToString(); 
string[] arrItemsPlanner = itemsPlanner.Split("______"); 

foreach (string i in arrItemsPlanner) 
{ 
  // Do something with each sentence
}
```

You can split over a string as well as char (or char[]).  In the foreach 'i' will be the value of the sentence, so you can concatenate it or process it or do whatever :)

If I've misunderstood, my apologies.  I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

From your example `i` does not contain a valid integer number, thus `Convert.ToInt32` fails. The `foreach` loop sets `i` with the current item in the sentences array, so basically `i` always contains one of the sentences in your main string. If you want `i` to be the index in the array, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx).

```
    string words = "This is a list of words______with a bit of punctuation" +
                   "______a tab character.";

    string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {'_'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string s in split) {

        if (s.Trim() != "")
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to trim your string before converting to a number? if thats not you may want to  use Int32.tryParse()

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code `foreach (string i in arrItemsPlanner)` 'i' will get the string value of arrItemsPlanner one by one. 
For exmaple on first iteration it will have 'Sentence number one' which is obviously not a vlid ont, hence your conversion failed.

Answer (score 0):

`i` only contains one of the string fragment which will be : `number one` `Sentence number two` and `Sentence number three`. If you want it to contain an int representing ht index, use :
1) a `for` loop
2) an `int` defined before your `foreach` and increase it (myInt++) in the `foreach` code !